# What file is always loaded with starting app engine instance?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to define some globals and load some modules (i.e. valid version of django) before any code is executed in app engine.

Is it any file in app engine where I can define startup code/configuration?

I think about Python language but other languages suggestion is also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this doc.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig  appengine_config.py is loaded before any of your code.

In addition to what the docs say, you can pretty much do anything. Manipulate sys.path, import, monkey patch stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.7, if you want to load a specific version of Django, call that version out in `app.yaml` as noted [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Configuring_Libraries) Django is one of the many supported [third-party libraries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27).

Answer (score 0):

An other way might be to use [warmup requests](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=el#Warmup_Requests). This is run on the request made in order to initialize a new server. It could be useful if you have a lot of thing to do and don't want the first request on a new server to stall... On the other hand, warmup requests can be sent even without finally using the new instance, so if you do have a lot of things to do you might end up using more instance hours. Check the documentation for more info.